# osrm-extract: command not found

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I've installed Ubuntu 16 on a VMware virtual machine. I've spent several days trying to figure out what I've missed or misunderstood.

When I run the osrm-extract on the north-american dataset, I get

> "osrm-extract: command not found"

Below is the terminal output relevant to the error I am getting.

```
jim@jim-virtual-machine:~/osrm-backend/build$ ls
cmake                  libosrm_customize.a           osrm-contract
CMakeCache.txt         libosrm_extract.a             osrm-customize
CMakeFiles             libosrm_partition.a           osrm-datastore
cmake_install.cmake    libosrm.pc                    osrm-extract
compile_commands.json  libosrm_store.a               osrm-partition
include                libosrm_update.a              osrm-routed
lib                    Makefile                      src
libosrm.a              north-america-latest.osm.pbf  unit_tests
libosrm_contract.a     osrm-components
jim@jim-virtual-machine:~/osrm-backend/build$ osrm-extract north-america-       latest.osm.pbf -p profiles/car.lua
osrm-extract: command not found
```

---

My goal is to run data analysis relating to food security issues within North American cities.  I want to run hundreds of thousands of routing queries. This is why I need the whole North American dataset.  I want to do comparisons between various cities.  My understanding of GIS & node theory is sufficient and I'm a pretty good PHP coder, however my Linux skills/understanding are marginal.  Any help would be appreciated.  If someone has a VMware machine instance which I can get a copy of, that would also be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepend `./` to run a local binary. I can recommend http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/ as a basic introduction into Bash CLI usage.

For your purpose it might be easier to run your queries against our public demo server (only for non-commercial use) https://router.project-osrm.org

Preparing the Na dataset locally will need about 64gb of memory and 200gb of disk space.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will run through the tutorials. On the memory issues, if I run queries within a localized area (ie point with radius of 10-20kms) will I run into memory issues with the NA dataset?

Comment: Yes this is just for processing the NA dataset prior to the query. The query radius does not determine which part of the road network will be explored by the search, it only determines the allowed range for coordinate snapping. (e.g. the nearest road to the input coordinate is at maximum 1km away)